# Returning to MS CRM page after login at external system

Tags: oauth-2.0, dynamics-crm

From MS CRM page, need to click button to route to external system for login (OAuth authentication), which automatically redirects back to a MS CRM page. The first part, the window for logging into external system, works fine. However, the redirect back to MS CRM is rejected due to the parameters in the url. MS CRM’s Parameter Filter rejects it. I need the parameters, which includes the OAuth auth code, which I then use to request the user’s access tokens.  I can disable CRM’s Parameter Filter via registry but that is not viable option (would require customers to edit registry on their servers).

Surely, this is a common use case. Like going from MS CRM to PayPal and back. Anyone have example or advice?  THANKS!

Comment: Are you redirecting back to a CRM entity form or custom webresource?

Answer (score 0):

CRM forces you to enter your parameters in a single Data Parameter:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg327945(v=crm.8)

If you have mulitple parameters, you'll need to have the returning service encodeURIComponent the values and set it to the data value: `http://<server name>/WebResources/new_/ShowDataParams.htm?Data=first%3DFirst%20Value%26second%3DSecond%20Value%26third%3DThird%20Value`

Comment: Thanks for replying! Part of my problem is that I have no control over the specific parameter names being returned. For example, parameters being returned include "state", "code" and "tssd".

Comment: You have to encode the parameters and their values into the Data URL Parameter

Comment: Yes, use of the Data parameter is only solution I found so far, but I do not control the parameters being returned. So, the only solution I’ve heard of would require a service external to MSCRM which the redirect_uri would point to, and the service would then repackage the parameters into the single Data parameter. I’m hoping Microsoft Support or someone else has a different solution. :)

Comment: How is it that the service that is directing you back to CRM doesn't support customization of the URL parameters?

Comment: The other system has defined their 'standard' process to return a specific set of parameters and is used by multiple systems, not just MSCRM. Naturally, they would prefer to not have a MSCRM-only version.

Comment: So the other system only accepts a base redirect URL, and it is hard coded as to the parameters that it appends to that Url?  You'd have to get the system to be able to edit how it returns parameters, or redirect it to a custom service, that then updates the params and redirects it to CRM with acceptable params...